# MongoDb Select Id, Created_time

Tags: mongodb

I have many records in Dbname in Collectionname

```
"_id" : ObjectId("53e32f83bca58515b6eee86e"),
"data" : [{              
    "id" : "7676722",
    "created_time" : "2014-03-16T17:06:49+0000"
}]
```

….

how select all id, created_time in Dbname in Collectionname ?

`sql analog = select id,created_time from Dbname.Collectionname`

Comment: The document shows elements inside an array. What is it you are actually trying to do? Just select those elements only as a separate result? Is there some other purpose? What is wrong with the contents just being returned within an array. These are the questions raised by your question, so you could be more clear if you want a better response than those given, which are not correct. Your "time" appears to be a string, which is not good unless you are just representing that way in shorthand and this is actually a date object.

Answer (score 0):

db.collection_name.find ({}, {data:1});

Comment: You could find answer on this page for SQL-MONGODB issues: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/